# Index of scalar NaNs in cell array

Tags: matlab, nan, cell-array

Consider the following cell array:

```
test = cell(2,2);
test(1,:) = {NaN};
test{2,1} = [1,2,3];
test{2,2} = [4,NaN,6];
```

I would like to identify those cells which directly consist of an NaN scalar. I tried `isnan` in conjunction with `cellfun`, however, that identifies all NaNs within a vector as well.

```
nanIdx = cellfun(@isnan, test, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

As a result I am looking for `nanIdx = [true,true ; false,false]` of type `logical`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the anonymous function as `@(x)isscalar(x) && isnan(x)`:

```
nanIdx = cellfun(@(x)isscalar(x) && isnan(x), test)
```

More conditions can be provided using any of [is*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/is.html) functions.

Comment: beautiful one liners

Comment: Indeed, very nice solution. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Glad If it can help!